# Is it possible to have a 2-page view in PDFTron?

Tags: winforms, pdftron, pdfnet

I looked over the PDFNet API references and sample code, but can't find any mention for having a 2-page view. Is it possible to have 2 pages on 1 pdfviewctrl in PDFNet ?

If I overlooked it, I apoligize in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both our WinForm (PDFViewCtrl) and WPF (PDFViewWPF) viewers support not only two page mode, but also cover two page mode (so two page magazine spreads are side by  side for example).

You want to call PDFViewCtrl.[SetPagePresentationMode](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/?topic=html/M_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewCtrl_SetPagePresentationMode.htm).

Available page modes [here](http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/docs/PDFNet/?topic=html/T_pdftron_PDF_PDFViewCtrl_PagePresentationMode.htm).